# Xamarin LaunchImage not listed as a source in ImageView properties

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, launch-screen

I'm working on a mobile app for iOS/Android. I'm using Visual Studio Community for Mac version 8.1.5, and the project was initially created as a new Tabbed Forms Xamarin App.

When the new project was created, the Assets.xcassets "folder" already contained two items - AppIcon and LaunchImage, with the LaunchImage screen looking like this:

[image]

I didn't create this, it already existed. There was also a LaunchScreen.storyboard file, and in the info.plist file, the **iPhone Launch Images** setting was already set to LaunchImage (the name of the image set in xcassets that already existed and which is shown in the screenshot above), and the **Launch Screen** setting was set to LaunchScreen:

[image]

I then added a bunch of images to a subfolder in the Resources folder, added each image to the correct box in the xcassets screen, saved everything and then tried to add an image to the LaunchScreen.storyboard file.

Unfortunately, when I add an Image View control to the Launch Screen, the Image dropdown in the widget properties does not list the LaunchScreen as an asset I can use!

If I create a new Image Set in the xcassets folder, it creates a screen like this:

[image]

This has nowhere near the number of different images sizes (I guess because it's a general image, not an image specifically for the launch screen), but, I *can* set the Image View on the launch screen to use this set.

So my question is: how can I use the LaunchImage screen (with its many different sizes for different devices) as the source of an Image View widget on the LaunchScreen story-board? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the guide for [Launch Screens for Xamarin.iOS Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos) .

You can pay attention to the third section of this chapter ([Managing Launch Screens with Storyboards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/launch-screens?tabs=macos#managing-launch-screens-with-storyboards)) ,

3. Add an **image** to the **Assets.xcassets** Asset Catalog so that it is available for use on the Launch Screen. For more information, see the [Adding Images to an Asset Catalog Image Set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos) section of the [Displaying an Image guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos).

**Explain**:

[image]

1. If clicking **Launch Image** selection. ImageView's droplist can not see it.Because this is used as System image, and if want to show in LauchScreen. You should set in **info.plist** as follow: (Only set Source , not set LaunchScreen)

[image]

2. If clicking **Image Set** In **Asset Cattalogs** , then ImageView's droplist can see added ImageSet Name there.But first need to set **info.plist** as follow:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I still have the same issue - as I mention in my answer, I am able to create a new ImageSet in xcassets, and then the new ImageSet *is* listed in the source for an ImageView, but the issue here is that there are only a couple of different resolution image placeholders, whereas in the LaunchImage set, there are many different resolutions. I even tried to create a new LaunchImage set, but I had the same problem - after adding all my images there, it does not show up in the image dropdown for ImageView control

Comment: @danwellman Hi, as my answer said, maybe explain is not clear. Actually `ImageView` can not use **LaunchImage set** , so droplist can not show. Then using **LaunchImage set**, can not be added in Imageview ,and should setting in **plist.info** Only set Source , not set LaunchScreen.https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DMRG.png The image in **LaunchImage set** also is the total view for launch view, can not be edited in storybord with other control.

Comment: So, the question is then, how to I use the LaunchImage set on the LaunchScreen? At the moment the LaunchScreen.storyboard is just a blank page - how do I add and position the LaunchScreen imageset there?

Comment: @danwellman Setting as the first explanation in the answer , can show LaunchScreen imageset there when lauching app.

Comment: @danwellman https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUm7q.png Here is your setting in **info.plist**. Setting this **Launch Screen** option to none can display LaunchScreen imageset .

Comment: I did try setting the Launch Screen option to none, but it didn't seem to make any difference. I've had to move on to another task for now, will try this again later. After setting it to none, do I need to do anything else (like add an ImageView control)? Or the LaunchScreen.storyboard will just start to use the Launch Screen image set?

Comment: Ok, I tried again. I added all my images to the LaunchImage item in xcassets, I set the Launch Screen option to none in info.plist - now it *is* using the images! Brilliant! But, instead of the blue background that I want in the launch screen, it is plain black - how can I set the bg colour of the launch screen now?

Comment: @danwellman Glad it works ! From shared the Screenshots of **LaunchImage Set** in question , showing black backgroud the reason is **LaunchImage set** not adding image inside it.I will show my sample image (https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB96G.png) .If need fit each screen size , should add each szie of image inside it.

Comment: I see - the background of the image should contain the BG colour. Perfect, thanks so much for the guidance :)